# How to return ftp response from ftp proxy, when request incoming to proxy is over http?

Tags: c#, http, tcp, proxy, ftp

At start thank you all for your kind help! Every hint is great and can teach me a lot, I appreciate every comment! Before you respond I'm aware that there is a lot of working solutions and working ftp proxies, but I'm asking this question for learning purposes and I try to understand how it works.

I have to implement my own ftp proxy server to capture ftp commands. The issue is that request incoming to proxy from client is over http protocol and when I return raw ftp response from ftp server through proxy to the client, then client browser is not able to handle this response as ftp response. Currently I'm trying to hardcode initial response from ftp proxy as following:

```
var clientWriter = new BinaryWriter(clientNetStream);
clientWriter.Write("220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)\r\n");
```

But when client browser got this response, then it is showing following box:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkT6A.jpg

Because above does not work then I've tried to include ftp response in HttpResponse as follows:

```
var clientWriter = new BinaryWriter(clientNetStream);
                        clientWriter.Write(
                            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                            "Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2004 16:18:20 GMT\r\n" +
                            "Server: Apache\r\n" +
                            "Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Jul 2004 17:29:19 GMT\r\n" +
                            "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n" +
                            "Content-Length: 9328\r\n" +
                            "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
                            "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                            "\r\n" +
                            "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3))\r\n");
```

But then browser handle this as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAYfJ.jpg

What I try do to is return "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)\r\n" response from server to the client and then I expect that client will send "USER anonymous\r\n" command to log in, but with both solutions this is not happening. I try to make working following sequence automatically (please see Wireshark screenshot). https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPoLi.jpg

Does anybody knows how to return response from server to the client, to make client to communicate with ftp server?

If client send http request to the proxy then can I return Ftp response instead of http response? If not, then how proxy response should looks like?

Comment: It looks like data is binary so you have to encode using Base 64 string.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. If the client is accessing the proxy using HTTP then you don't have to implement a FTP server but a HTTP server since the client will not send any FTP commands in this case and not expect any FTP responses. If the client accesses a `ftp://` URL without a configured proxy it will do real FTP. If the client instead accesses a `ftp://` URL through a proxy it will do HTTP and not FTP and expect the proxy to do all the FTP with the remote server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the answer. Then how the client can make get command?
As I understood proxy server should log in to ftp server and return directory listing to the client over http response.

Comment: @Michal16511: it is unclear for me what your problem you are facing. Is your goal to implement a HTTP proxy which can forward requests to a FTP server? Is your goal to implement something which looks like a HTTP proxy to the client but answers everything by its own? Is your goal to implement a FTP server (no proxy involved)? Or even something else?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I want to implement ftp proxy, but I'm facing issue when client browser displays raw response from the ftp server as text (list of files in directory) instead of building html with directory listing and links to the files. Should I retrieve directory listing from ftp server and then in proxy create links with appropriate html and then return this html to the client?

Comment: @Michal16511: Browsers don't support FTP proxies (and there is no really a specification of what an FTP proxy exactly is). Browser support HTTP proxies which are able to forward requests to an FTP server. These HTTP proxies speak HTTP to the browser and FTP to the server, i.e. they don't speak FTP to the browser as you try. They just take the HTTP request for a file, then login to the FTP server, change to the directory, retrieve the file and then provide the file in the HTTP response to the browser. The browser does not see any of the FTP stuff, it only sees the retrieved file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hah. I had wrong assumption what ftp proxy really is. Thank you for clarification, you are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between a `HTTP` Proxy and a `FTP` proxy.
A HTTP proxy is typically capably to handle URLs starting with `http(s)://` and `ftp://`.
For URLs starting with `ftp://`, the proxy does a protocol transformation.

That means that the client uses the `HTTP` protocol to transmit the URL to the proxy (in this case starting with `ftp://`). Due to the URL starts with `ftp://`, the proxy knows that it must use the `FTP` protocol to connect to the server. This is referred to as `FTP over HTTP` as the client is connecting to a FTP server using a HTTP client.

Alternatively, the client can use a native FTP client to connect to the server using the proxy. In this case, the client uses the `FTP` protocol to talk to the proxy and the proxy uses the `FTP` protocol to talk to the server. This is referred to as `native FTP proxy`.

As you already noticed, in the `FTPoverHTTP` scenario, the client does not follow up on any `FTP` response. Instead, you have to implement the protocol transformation in the proxy accordingly. Pass the username and password from client to proxy as follows: `ftp://username:password@server.com`. Your proxy must extract the credentials from the URL, connect to the server, and then issue the `USER` and `PASS` command on behalf of the client.

Hint: The proxy also needs to extract directory/filenames from the URL in order to get a directory listing / file content using the `FTP` protocol from the server, then present it to the client accordingly, e.g. directory listing as html page with links to the artifacts in the directory or in case a file has been accessed, send a response which triggers a `HTTP` file download on the client